# Identificanto formato de dados em web service

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-request, http-headers

Boa noite!
Estou implementado um serviço em um sistema para outros sistemas consumirem.
Esse sistema consome dados nos formatos XML e JSON.
Quero saber se tem alguma maneira de identificar quando o usuário enviar uma string no formato XML.
Eis o meu código.

```
        $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'http://www.e-sms.com.br/api',
            data: { xml : "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <note> <to>Tove</to> <from>Jani</from> <heading>Reminder</heading> <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> </note>"},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (request){
                console.log(request);
            }
        });        
    });
```

Esse código,funciona quando a propriedade ContentType é removida.
Até o momento, estou acreditando que o ContentType é o segredo.
Meu Servidor tem o seguinte cabeçalho.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
```

cabeçalho, no lado do servidor usa o Content-Type padrão.
Eu acredito que ao definir esse atributo na minha requisição Ajax, eu estaria sujerindo ao servidor que o utilize.
Mas não estou conseguindo fazer o negócio funcionar.
Será que alguém consegue me ajudar ?

Comment: Usar o ContentType é errado nesse caso. Repare que você não está enviando um conteúdo XML, mas sim um objeto onde existe uma variavel de nome "xml" que por sua vez possui uma string do tipo texto, sendo esse texto um xml. Sobre os cabeçalhos `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` e `Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8` não adianta colocar os 2, pois o segundo substitui o primeiro. Faça uma condição `if` para decidir qual o php deve considerar.